# How to inspect elements in Winium

Tags: python, selenium, winium

I have started using Winium automation tool to automate windows apps. I am new to this tool and I am not finding any documentation for solving my doubts.

Following is the basic code that I have refered to start using Winium.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:9999',
    desired_capabilities={
        "debugConnectToRunningApp": 'false',
        "app": r"C:/windows/system32/notepad.exe"
    })

window = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Notepad")
window.send_keys("example text")
```

My query is how we inspect elements in windows applications ?
Above code will open Notepad and will type "example text" in it.It finds the text field using driver.find_element_by_class_name("Notepad").Similarly how can I inspect other elements of the Notepad window.Like File menu option?
Also it would be really nice if anyone provides me link for a documentation of Winium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the element OR  properties of a windows application we use “**Inspect.exe**” which is available by default in windows if not just download it.It gives all the properties of a desktop application to control it.

[Inspect.exe documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects)

[Basic Winium Example](https://asifahmedsarja.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/windows-application-desktop-automation-with-winium/)

[Resource link](https://github.com/2gis/Winium)

[image: Winium Inspector]

For More information about Windows based UI Inspector refer this : 
[more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/testing-tools?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

*Also you can use :* **UI SPY**

[image]

Comment: Is "UI Spy" available in Windows 10 by default?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim : No, UI Spy does not come by default with Windows.